# How to get div style in iframe by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

There is a iframe with Youtube video on the webpage I am going to visit, and I can use jQuery to get a div in the iframe. However, I cannot get its style(such as background-image) of the div. Any solution?

HTML code is given below:

```
<iframe width="600" height="344" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aaaaa?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
  <div class="ytp-thumbnail-overlay" data-layer="4" style="background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/JPkV4li7FVQ/sddefault.webp');">
    This is a div in iframe
  </div>
</iframe>
```

jQuery code follows below:

```
var div = $("iframe>div.ytp-thumbnail-overlay");//Here div is not undefined.
var url = div.css('background-image');//Here url is undefined, why and how to get it?
```

Comment: `$("ifrmae>` should be `$("iframe>`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the jQuery code. :) @Guruprasad Rao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things blocking your way here. First, an iframe is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), so the html inside `<iframe></iframe>` gets removed and replaced with the contents of the iframe when the page loads.

Secondly, the [same origin policy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is stopping you from using a script to retrieve any data from inside the iframe, so you can't retrieve the background image YouTube generates for `div.ytp-thumbnail-overlay`, anyway.